# Generate HTML table with Flying Saucer - ugly style

Tags: html, itext, css-tables, flying-saucer

I want to implement a HTML table with **Flying Saucer** (a project that uses iText 2.1.7 to create PDF). If I create the PDF file, the table is very ugly. 
If I copy the generated code into another HTML Editor, for example: http://www.quackit.com/html/online-html-editor/ everything is fine

Everything is fine.
Here are the examples:

iText
[image]

in Online HTML Editor (note: in the screenhot is only one row available)
[image]

Below my generated code for the table:

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 135.0mm; left: 20.0mm; height: 105.0mm; width: 180.0mm;"><table cellspacing="1.0mm" cellpadding="1.0mm" border="0.0mm" border-style="none" border-color="#000000" frame="none" rules="all"><thead><tr><th valign="middle" style="height: 10.0mm; width: 70.0mm;"><div style="text-align: center;"><span style="text-align: center; font-size:11px; font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; color: #000000;"><strong>Artikelnr</strong></span></div></th><th valign="middle" style="height: 10.0mm; width: 70.0mm;"><div style="text-align: center;"><span style="text-align: center; font-size:11px; font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; color: #000000;"><strong>Beschreibung</strong></span></div></th><th valign="middle" style="height: 10.0mm; width: 70.0mm;"><div style="text-align: center;"><span style="text-align: center; font-size:11px; font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; color: #000000;"><strong>Menge</strong></span></div></th></tr></thead><tr><td><span style="font-size:11px; font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif"></span></td><td><span style="font-size:11px; font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif"></span></td><td><span style="font-size:11px; font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif">1.0</span></td></tr><tr><td><span style="font-size:11px; font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif"></span></td><td><span style="font-size:11px; font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif"></span></td><td><span style="font-size:11px; font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif">1.0</span></td></tr></table></div>
```

Here my code for generating the PDF file:

```
>       
// Clean up the HTML to be well formed          
String str = HTML code......
HtmlCleaner cleaner = new
> HtmlCleaner();            CleanerProperties props = cleaner.getProperties();
>           TagNode node = cleaner.clean(str);          new
> PrettyXmlSerializer(props).writeToStream(node, out);
> 
>           
// Create the PDF           
OutputStream os = out;          ITextRenderer
> renderer = new ITextRenderer();           renderer.setDocumentFromString(new
> String(out.toByteArray())); //            renderer.setDocumentFromString(str);
>           renderer.layout();          renderer.createPDF(out);            os.close();
```

Can anybody help me, please.
What´s wrong.
Is this a know issue?

Comment: You are blaming iText for problems caused by Flying Saucer. Flying Saucer is a project that *uses* iText. The owners of the project you are using are **in no way** affiliated with iText!

Answer (score 2):

I guess the issue you are getting is due a css property of the table. Flying saucer allows you to specify the padding between rows.

Try something like this

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```